# Google Sheet Function to calculate blance

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script

I am trying to take this formula and trying to expand it to the whole Column as opposed to having it per cell..

This sheet is for real estate.  Taking balance from previous month balance and adding expenses and subtracting payments.

Currently we have

`=SUM(H4,C5,G5)-F5`

---

Currently after HOURS of research I found this which was not much help

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/71291?hl=en

Comment: Can you produce a sample of how your spreadsheet looks like

Comment: Thank you for the many swift replies, I took a quick screenshot of what we are trying to do.

http://s29.postimg.org/6ev2oquk7/image001.png

Also,

https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0AmwdQ7lLmX2adGwyQzhQOUR2SThJeEQwdTBjUWZWZUE&mode=public

This template above helped but we are trying to add 3 more columns to the payments without breaking the formula!

Comment: I was able to tinker with the example and I came across this formula seems to help.

Is there a more efficient way to do it?
<hr>
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(D5),ISBLANK(E5),ISBLANK(F5),ISBLANK(G5),ISBLANK(H5)),"",OFFSET(I5,-1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0)+E5-D5+F5+G5+H5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered by Adam Lusk here: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/fEXrwNolJYU

I have published a quick example with a non-working formula using OFFSET here:
http://goo.gl/NF6T24

The formula that works:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(D2 - SUMIF(ROW(A3:A20),"<="&ROW(A3:A20),A3:A20) + SUMIF(ROW(A3:A20),"<="&ROW(A3:A20),B3:B20))`